# Overlay image/map on MapView?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, annotations

Okay, hope you can help med here :)
I have been searching everywhere to figure this out, but haven't had any luck.

I know about Annotations and how to overlay them on a map on the iPhone. 
But what if I have location like in the forest where there arent any roads or anything. 
What I am asking is, how can I overlay a custom image (map) over the Map view so that it zooms the right way like the map, in the right scale, and can I add my own annotations on top of the custom image/map?

Hop I was clear enough on what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable but challenging using the 3.2 version of the SDK.  See http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108.

If you can wait until June, 2010 to release your app, you should consider using the SDK 4 beta.  As I'm writing this, the SDK is still under NDA, so I'm very limited in what I can tell you, but I can quote Apple's public statements about [What's New in iPhone OS 4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html):

> Mapping applications can now include
>   overlays that can identify regions on
>   a map. Draw routes with annotations
>   for customized directions and other
>   functionalities.

Comment: Great, will be looking forward to the 4.0 release then :) Thanks